# Help reverse engineering a CRC-8

Tags: arduino, reverse-engineering, algorithm, crc

I have an arduino based home temperature monitoring system using Ambient Weather F007th wireless Thermo-Hygrometers as sensors. I am trying to work out the CRC and add some code to my project to reduce the number of bad readings.

I have 1000s of sample readings and from that have constructed two sample data sets with 1 bit difference. The last byte is the CRC.

1. - FD   45   77   14   80   31   A5
   - FD   45   77   14   81   31   E6
   - FD   45   77   14   82   31   23
   - FD   45   77   14   84   31   98
   - FD   45   77   14   88   31   DF
2. - FD   45   7B   44   80   30   FD
   - FD   45   7B   44   81   30   BE
   - FD   45   7B   44   82   30   7B
   - FD   45   7B   44   84   30   C0
   - FD   45   7B   44   88   30   87

Using advice from other sites I have identified that the XOR of the first CRC against the following CRC produces the same sequence for both sets.

1. - A5 ^ E6 = 43
   - A5 ^ 23 = 86
   - A5 ^ 98 = 3D
   - A5 ^ DF = 7A
2. - FD ^ BE = 43
   - FD ^ 7B = 86
   - FD ^ C0 = 3D
   - FD ^ 87 = 7A

I have also established that this sequence represents lines 14 to 17 of the 0x31 CRC-8.

But now I am stuck. I cannot replicate the CRC results with other data.

I would appreciate any ideas. I have thousands of datapoints if anybody wants more

Comment: I don't think an exhaustive search should take long, if you don't feel like doing it yourself there is http://reveng.sourceforge.net/

Comment: This question might be a better fit on the reverse engineering specific StackExchange.

Comment: Why don't you just write a program to try all 8 bit CRCs, there aren't that many.